How to save and retrieve a JSON directly in latest version of RealmDB-Kotlin in Android during runtime without RealmObject Using RealmDB - Kotlin
I need to store and retrieve a JSON in ReamDB in runtime without creating a RealmObject for that. Also want to check whether the particular JSON object is present in the DB already using a giving field (like “id”). If it exists, then update the object,If not, then save it as new object.
How to do this in latest version of RealmDB Kotlin SDK in Android.
I searched internet but all examples throw “unresolved references” for classes. It seems they are deprecated and removed.It seems they are deprecated and removed. Also, most internet articles are using Java SDK or Realm-Android(a java extn for Android) but I need Kotlin SDK which also targets Kotlin Multi platform.
Please help me.

There are several ways you can interact with the Atlas server that backs Realm.
One is to utilize the Realm SDK - which provides a very object-centric front end to the back-end JSON data and server.
By the question though, it sounds like you want to circumvent Realm entirely and work directly with Atlas. Atlas fully support REST calls and you can also work with App Services for that task. App services and the app client:

The App client is the client-side interface to the App Services
backend. It lets you interact with your App Services App and provides
access to App Services functionality, including:
Authenticating app users
Synchronizing data between the Atlas backend and the client app using
Device Sync
Calling Atlas functions

Connection to App services is as simple as
// Creates an App with default configuration values
val app = App.create(YOUR_APP_ID) // Replace with your App ID

then you can for example, call an app function, like one that sums two numbers
val response = user.functions.call<Int>("sum", 1, 2)

You could call functions to insert data, perform a query or a wide variety of other tasks.
It's covered in the SDK documentation
I would recommend though, leveraging the Realm SDK for those tasks as it performs a lot of the heavy lifting and allow you to focus on client side code and the UI instead of messy server functions.
